# Is there a tab equivalent of std::endl within the standard library?

Tags: c++, std

Using C++, is there an equivalent standard library constant for `'\t'` like there is for a newline?

Ideally:

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << std::tab << "text";
```

If not, why is this the case?

(I'm aware I can just insert a `'\t'` but I'd like to sate my curiosity).

Answer (score 109, accepted):

No. `std::endl` isn't a newline constant. It's a *manipulator* which, *in addition* to inserting a newline, also *flushes* the stream.

If you *just* want to add a newline, you're supposed to just insert a `'\n'`. And if you just want to add a tab, you just insert a `'\t'`. There's no `std::tab` or anything because inserting a tab plus flushing the stream is not exactly a common operation.

Comment: @Ksletmo, the sequence inserted by `endl` is always `'\n'`; it has nothing to do with the platform's preferred text-file line ending.

Comment: To put that another way: the newline character `'\n'` is a standard ASCII character just like `'\t'` is. The effect of writing the single character `'\n'` to a file opened in text mode varies by platform. As Rob says, that's nothing to do with `std::endl`, which just writes a character and does a flush. It doesn't know or care what the stream does with that character.

Comment: How is `foo << '\t'` different that `foo << 10` ('\t' is encoded as a 10 in ascii). I want a tab, not a formatted 10.

Answer (score 26):

If you want to add the feature yourself, it would look like this:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace std {
  template <typename _CharT, typename _Traits>
  inline basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits> &
  tab(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits> &__os) {
    return __os.put(__os.widen('\t'));
  }
}

int main() {

  std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::tab << "world" << std::endl;
}
```

I don't recommend doing this, but I wanted to add a solution for completeness.

Answer (score 4):

No.

There are only `std::ends` (insert null character) and `std::flush` (flush the stream) output manipulators besides `std::endl` in ostream include file.

You can find others in ios and iomanip include files. Full list is [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip)

Answer (score 4):

Actually, it is not needed.

Because `endl` first does the same job of inserting a newline as `\n`, and then also flushes the buffer.

Inserting `\t` on a stream does not require to flush it after .